# What whitespaces in HTML are considered whitespace nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Aren't the white spaces immediately following the opening html tag and immediately before the closing html tag whitespace nodes? Consider the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Data</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Warning</li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div>Top Secret!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, when I look at the rendered page in Firebug, I see that the 'head' node has a 'title' node and 2 'whitespace' nodes on either side of it. Which is what I expect. Similarly I had expected to see 'whitespace' nodes between `<html>` and `<head>` and between the `</body>` and `</html>`. But that isn't the case. Why does Firebug not consider them as whitespaces?

You can also try this on [this](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/) online DOM viewer.

Comment: This is a wild guess of mine, but content is not allowed between `<html>` and `<head>` as well as between `</body>` and `</html>` so white space in those locations should not affect content.

Comment: However, this contradicts what https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Whitespace_in_the_DOM states.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. What's your version of Firefox?

Comment: @user1835565 On Firefox 33.0.2

Comment: When you say firebug, do you mean the plug-in or the integrated tool you get with F12? If it's the plug-in I don't use it anymore.

Comment: @user1835565 I mean the F12. Also try the online DOM viewer here - http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/

Comment: It looks like the dom viewer is able to see them, but I still see nothing in firebug. I'm sorry I can't do anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it deserves a proper answer, if only because browsers handle the two cases (1) between `<html>` and `<head>` and (2) between `</body>` and `</html>` differently.

In the first case, browsers simply discard the space characters. The ["before head" insertion mode](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode) of the tree construction stage of the HTML parser requires that the spaces are discarded. Although this is unusual, it's most likely for backward compatibility. In the days before CSS, it's likely that browsers would have needed to discard such characters to stop odd spaces appearing at the start of displayed document.

In the second case, the space characters are not discarded, they are added to the DOM document. But they are not added as a text node *after* the body element, but just inside the end of it. So there is no text node to be displayed in the DOM viewers between `</body>` and `</html>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla, all whitespace in the text content of the original document is represented in the DOM.
This does not include whitespace within tags.

So this means that:
a)there will be some text nodes that contain only whitespace
b)some text nodes will have whitespace at the beginning or end.

Hope this helps.